# How to use mysql2 library with Sapper?

Tags: node.js, svelte, rollup, sapper, node-mysql2

I am creating an application in Svelte Sapper. I have a `routes/account/login.js` API route where I am trying to use [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2). The route itself works (I checked with Postman), but as soon as I import mysql, the server crashes and an error appears:

```sh
[rollup-plugin-svelte] The following packages did not export their `package.json` file so we could not check the "svelte" field. If you had difficulties importing svelte components from a package, then please contact the author and ask them to export the package.json file.

- mysql2
```

```js
import mysql from "mysql2/promise";

export async function post(req, res) {
  //route test
  const { login, password } = req.body;
  res.end(`${login}, ${password}`);
}
```

What can I do to make this import work?
What can I do to make this import work?

The Sapper documentation doesn't say anything about whether you need to change something in the configuration additionally. https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Server_routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I had to create a `@lib` folder in the `src/node_modules` folder and there file eg. `db.js`. In that file instead of `import` you need to use `require()`! and then you have to export the function that connects to the database. and then you can import that in the path

```js
//src/node_modules/@lib/db.js
const mysql = require("mysql2");

export async function connectToDatabase() {
  return mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    ....
  })
}
```

```js
//routes/account/login.js
import { query } from "@lib/db";
export async function post(req, res) {
  ...
}
```